# Sometimes strange artifact appears when [mapView selectAnnotation];

Tags: ios5, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

```
[_mapView selectAnnotation:sannotation animated:YES];
```

[image: Screenshot]

It appears not always, so I don't understand what's the reason for it.

How to fix it?

Comment: Before selecting any annotation deselct all annotations on mapView.

Comment: @chatur Can you please place your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before selecting any annotation deselect all annotations on mapView.

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) 
  [mymap deselectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
```

I had same issue when along with default callout, I had implemented custom callouts. Though it is not  a perfect solution it served the purpose.