# MKAnnotationView's callout bubble doesn't appear properly

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have an app including a MKMapView with MKPinAnnotationViews. Each time I select an annotationView, the subtitle must be updated and the new subtitle appears.

In order to update the subtitle I wrote this code :

```
- (void)                    mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view

{    
    ((MyAnnotation *) view.annotation).subtitle =  //new subtitle...
}
```

Therefore, when I select my annotationView, the subtitle is properly updated but the callout bubble doesn't appear properly. It is cut in several parts an the arrow doen't point on the pin anymore. I seems that the callout view'size is not updated (or something like that).
What can I do ?

Thank you very much !
Gilles

Comment: i have also faced this weird issue before on simulator. I believe it worked fine on Device for me.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of this issue? It's hard to help when we can't see what's going on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180317/sometimes-strange-artifact-appears-when-mapview-selectannotation/9205668#9205668, might help

Comment: You need to set the title and subtitle when you add annotations, or to add the annotations when the map moves or when something you use for the title or sub gets updated. You cannot change the title or subtitle after displaying the callout and expect the callout to resize: dimensions are calculated _before_ it appears, not after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the annotation view a title or it won't work properly.  You can use a garbage value like @"..." I don't think a blank string will work.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the problem because there is a title already. The bubble appears ... but not properly. It is vertically cut in three parts and the arrow doesn't point on the pin anymore.